# Any foreign key must be automatically required?

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5

I had a model named Tarefa (Task in Portuguese):

```
public class Tarefa
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Assunto { get; set; }

    public int ClienteID { get; set;  }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

    public int ProcessoID { get; set; }
    public virtual Processo Processo { get; set; }        
}
```

ClienteID and ProcessoID (NOT REQUIRED)

I do not need to select them when I create a new Tarefa.

After Scaffolding, add-migration and update-database the table definition show:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tarefas] (
[ID]                INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Assunto]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[ClienteID]         INT            NOT NULL,
[ProcessoID]        INT            NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Tarefas] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Tarefas_dbo.Clientes_ClienteID] FOREIGN KEY ([ClienteID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Clientes] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Tarefas_dbo.Processoes_Pasta (se ajuizado)] FOREIGN KEY ([ProcessoID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Processoes] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

);

Why this 2 columns are NOT NULL?

Comment: Because you used `int`. If you want them to be nullable, then use a nullable type `int?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default foreign keys field are not null. If you need specifically any foreign key to be null, use nullable over there.
Like use,

`public int? ClienteID { get; set;  }` instead of

`public int ClienteID { get; set;  }`

similarly for `public int ProcessoID { get; set; }`